# TortoiseSVN works but command line svn doesn't work?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN normally and it works fine. Whenever I try to use SVN from the command line I get an

```
c:\code\MyProject> svn status
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

error even though it's the same directory that I usually work with using TortoiseSVN.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Why tag it not-programming-related?  Its about a prominent programming tool that is malfunctioning...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that both TortoiseSVN and SVN are the same client versions. In Windows Explorer, do Right Click -> TortoiseSVN -> About. Your version information will look like this:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.6.5, Build 16974 - 32 Bit , 2009/08/20 08:13:46
Subversion 1.6.5,
apr 1.3.8
apr-utils 1.3.9
neon 0.28.6
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
zlib 1.2.3
```

So mine is client version "Subversion 1.6.5". From the command line do:

```
svn --version
```

You'll get something like this:

```
svn, version 1.6.4 (r38063)
compiled Aug  5 2009, 12:42:52

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.</pre>
```

Small version differences are usually OK. Big differences are likely to cause a problem.

The other thing to check is that you are storing SVN information in ".svn" directories for both versions. TortoiseSVN lets you change to use "_svn" instead of ".svn" (in Tortoise SVN -> Settings -> General). This may cause you a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to go one folder deeper to see if you have the same problem.

```
c:\code\MyProject\folder> svn status
```

or

```
c:\code\MyProject> svn status folder
```

Comment: I understand how svn works...I am definitely in a working directory.  No matter where I type svn status from I get that message.

Comment: As Steve N pointed out before, verify if your svn admin folders are named .svn or _svn. If the latter you will need a custom built command line svn.exe that handles the _svn folders.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have not given the full path to your svn instal when trying to run "svn".  For example:

`TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /url:"< < your repository url>>" /path:"< < your working copy path>>" /closeonend:1 /notempfile 
/`

You are better off just using the GUI.

P.S. TortoiseProc.exe must be in your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the response - what does the code you posted do?  I would use the GUI but sometimes the command line is faster - especially when TortoiseProc chokes up

Comment: I have edited the command in my example to be more explicit.  I hope that helps.

Comment: if you want to run the command line just download the SVN binary http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100